# "getDate is not a function" after adding the timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone

I am displaying a real-time date and time but I am getting the error `getDate is not a function`.

I am getting this error because I added timezone like this

```
var x = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
```

Would you help me out on this issue?

```js
function calculateUSATime() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('currentUSATime()', refresh)
}


function currentUSATime() {
  var x = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York"
  });
  var date = x.getDate();
  var month = x.getMonth(); //Be careful! January is 0 not 1
  var year = x.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = date;
  calculateUSATime();
}
```

```html
<body onload=currentUSATime();>
  <span id='ct'></span>

</body>
```

Comment: I think It's because you're adding a timezone. The internal representation of a date to js is a number, the number of milliseconds from 1970 until now. There's nothing to accommodate the adding of a timezone of you're subsequently trying to use getDate()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toLocaleString` will return a `String`. You can pass it again to date constructor to get the instance of `Date`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

> The `toLocaleString()` method **returns a string** with a language sensitive representation of this date

```js
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];


function calculateUSATime() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('currentUSATime()', refresh)
}


function currentUSATime() {
  let str = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York"
  })
  var x = new Date(str);
  var date = x.getDate();
  var month = x.getMonth(); //Be careful! January is 0 not 1
  var year = x.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = days[x.getDay()]+ ' ' + x.toLocaleString();
  calculateUSATime();
}
```

```html
<body onload=currentUSATime();>
  <span id='ct'></span>

</body>
```

Another thing you can improve it that remove `calculateUSATime` and use `setTimeout` inside `currentUSATime`.

```js
function currentUSATime() {
  let str = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York"
  })
  var x = new Date(str);
  var date = x.getDate();
  var month = x.getMonth(); //Be careful! January is 0 not 1
  var year = x.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
  
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout(currentUSATime, refresh)
  
}
```

```html
<body onload="currentUSATime();">
  <span id='ct'></span>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes, In your snippet, It's working. Can you add x instated of date in this   document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;

Comment: can you help me one more. I have to display "Thursday"  "11/04/2019 " " Time here".

Comment: Oh! Yes. So I have to do the same for the year because I need 11/04/2019..correct?

Comment: Just pass additional arguments to toLocaleString: `let str = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/New_York", weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second: "2-digit" }); console.log(str);`. That is all you need. No need to parse and format again.

Comment: @SalmanA, Thanks for the help, MaheerAli, I will check moment.js. thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Comment: @MaheerAli - Unfortunately, the approach you suggest is flawed.  I explain in detail in my answer below.  SalmanA's suggestion is the correct approach.

Comment: @MattJohnson, but SalmanA answer is not working like real time. It's displaying in the console but when I  refresh the page then it's changing the time. I need real live time

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, `toLocaleString` returns a `string`, and thus you cannot treat it as a `Date` object.  Since you appear to want to display it as a string anyway, then the correct approach is to simply pass *all* of the arguments that you need to get the string in the desired format.

For example:

```
var s = new Date().toLocaleString(undefined, { 
    timeZone: 'America/New_York',
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
})
```

This gives the current time in `America/New_York` (US Eastern Time), using the user's locale for formatting (`undefined` defaults to the user's locale), and specifies that the full name of the weekday should be given, along with the numeric format of the date and time.

Example outputs depending on the user's locale:

```
en-US    "Thursday, 4/11/2019, 1:13:14 PM"
en-GB    "Thursday, 11/04/2019, 13:13:14"
fr-FR    "jeudi 11/04/2019 à 13:13:14"
zh-CN    "2019年4月11日星期四 下午1:13:14"
```

You can read all of the options in [the `toLocaleString` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

It was also suggested in a different answer that you could take the output of `toLocaleString` and parse it with the `Date` object's constructor.  That approach is not recommended, for the following reasons:

- The ECMAScript specification does *not* require that these strings can be handled by the `Date` parser.  It only requires parsing of ISO8601 compliant strings, such as `"2019-04-11T13:13:14"`.  Anything else at all (even if it looks simple like `"4/11/2019, 1:13:14 PM"`) is implementation dependent.  In other words, not all browsers will agree on how to parse these strings, and some will refuse to, giving `Invalid Date`.
- The `Date` object's parser will always use the user's current locale.  So if you did hardcode the locale to `en-US` in the `toLocaleString` call, then parsed it in the UK, you would erroneously flip the month and day components.  April 11th would be treated as November 4th.
- When you parse a string that looks like local time with the `Date` object, it will rightly assume that it is in the user's local time zone.  There are consequences of that.  Consider that you may be passing a date and time that are valid in `America/New_York`, but are invalid in the user's local time zone.  For example, March 31st 2019 at 1:30 AM is valid in the US, but would be invalid in the UK because it falls into their spring-forward DST gap (the clocks in the UK advanced from 00:59 to 02:00, skipping over that hour).  In this case, the behavior is undefined.  You may get `Invalid Date`, or you may get 00:30 or 02:30, but you won't get 01:30.
- If you did reconstruct a `Date` object, if the user's time zone is different than the one given, you're creating a very different point in time.  If you then passed that `Date` object into something else, it would have no idea that you meant US Eastern Time. Ultimately, `Date` objects don't keep track of dates, but rather they keep a Unix Timestamp, which is related strictly to UTC.  Indeed, the name `Date` is confusing and inappropriate (IMHO).

Comment: Oh! You shared the great information. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate your answer. Upvote from my side.

Comment: Can create a snippet for the output?